# mysqld not responding

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Has anyone seen this before?

```
[host@user init.d]$ mysqld stop
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'stop').
Use --help to get a list of available options
[host@user init.d]$ mysqld restart
[host@user init.d]$ mysqld start --user=mysql &
[1] 6782
[host@user init.d]$ mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').
Use --help to get a list of available options

[1]+ Exit 1 mysqld start --user=mysql
```

Any straightforward reason for this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `which mysqld` and see which file is executed by you. I think it will be something like `/usr/bin/mysqld` or `/usr/sbin/mysqld`.

The program you want to call is `/etc/init.d/mysqld`, or `/etc/init.d/mysql`, or similar.